# Using a Date to refer to a page to VLOOKUP into

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I currently have data that has a date and item number and I'm looking to pull the price from a different sheet.

```
=Vlookup(#,Jan1!(Range),2,0)
```

Gives me my price of Jan 1

```
=Vlookup(#,Jan3!(Range),2,0)
```

Gives me my price of Jan 3

The problem is that each date has its own sheet but I want a single formula to find the date of the data to reference the sheet correlating to that date.

My end goal is to have a formula that references the date to go and do a `vlookup` on the related sheet.

```
=Vlookup(#,[Order Date's Referenced Page](Range),2,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to use INDIRECT to specify this:

```
=VLOOKUP(#,INDIRECT("'"&A11&"'!"&"A2:B8"),2,0)
```

Where A11 is your sheet name, A2:B8 is of course your range. These are simply strings you can manipulate however you need to. Without a sample of the data you're working with, I can't say exactly what tweaks may need making, but hopefully puts you on the right path.